# "Waiting to install" for ever - Ubuntu Software - 16.04

Tags: software-center, 16.04

When I try to install .deb files with "Ubuntu Software", it keeps "Waiting to install" for ever.

Comment: This is a high priority bug and will be fixed soon. In the mean time u can use `dpkg` to install .deb files via terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: Why did they release it as a new version of Ubuntu if it doesn't work yet? Not being able to manage packages with a package manager.... I wouldn't exactly call it a "bug".

Comment: Agreed...its a problem.  But its also an opportunity....to read your mail, hug your wife or child, or walk your dog.  The app still gets the job done

Comment: How is this still a problem over a year later??

Comment: Oct 2017- normal world users still cant install Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 - Donwload the old "Ubuntu software center" in the new "Ubuntu software".

2 - `unity --reset-icons` or Restart your computer (to remove the "waiting to install")

3 - Open the .deb file with the just installed "Ubuntu software center"

4 - Install it

Comment: In 1) it shows "waiting for install" forever. After 2) the old "Ubuntu software center" is not installed.

Comment: careful with `unity --reset-icons`: it closes all program and reset the unity launcher as it is originally (in ubuntu install) !

Answer (score 26):

**Install .deb packages from the terminal:**

```
$ sudo dpkg -i <path/to/deb.deb>
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

The reasoning behind apt-get install -f from the man page:

```
 -f, --fix-broken
           Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can
           omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely
           correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow
           broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so
           corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending
           packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item:
           APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

<sub>Credit: Mohit Rajan's comment</sub>

Comment: All this does is open the software center and continues to not work

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Could you explain why do you need `sudo apt-get install -f` in order to install a package, if `dpkg` already does it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ./file.deb` or `sudo apt-get install /path/to/file.deb` is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, Not sure if it should help but, if you frequently install packages from .deb files it's advisable to use a reliable package handler like [Gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/)

However, if you like to browse for apps and install them from the same place, you should stick to Ubuntu Software Center. To trash Gnome-Software and install the classic and trusted Ubuntu Software Center follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/782999/is-there-any-safe-way-to-remove-gnome-software-center-in-16-04-and-install-the-c).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we are all affected by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206.

Unfortunately there is no other solution than using another package manager to install these packages.

Answer (score 0):

[Workaround was proposed and filed as another bug related to this issue.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1594080)

> All you need to do is log out, and then login again.

Tested and verified this workaround fixes the issue on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, clean installation.