# Is there any safe way to remove GNOME Software in 16.04 and install the classic Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gnome-software

GNOME Software (the default software center in Ubuntu 16.04, also called Ubuntu Software) is annoying! It keeps checking for updates and throws pop-ups in my face the whole day and thus mooches my net and also makes it very disturbing to use my machine. Is there any 100% safe means to remove it and install the classic Ubuntu Software Center (the default software center till Ubuntu 15.10)? Also, will the packages in the classic one be up to date?

Comment: You could also just configure Software to not do that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It will be safe to remove `gnome-software`, `apt` tells me it will only take out the package `gnome-software` and nothing else, I tried it, it was removed and the system is fine

```
sudo apt purge gnome-software
```

To add the old one back run

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

All packages will be exactly the same, it is based off you repositories, not the center its self.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Also, will the packages in the classic one be up to date?

There will be no difference - you will get the same packages either way.