# Is there any drawback to remove gnome-software and packagekit in Artful?

Tags: gnome-software

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/782999/is-there-any-safe-way-to-remove-gnome-software-center-in-16-04-and-install-the-c) but it was for 16.04. As Artful will use gnome-shell, is there any drawback to remove these two packages and their dependencies and use apt or Synaptic as I am used to since ten years?

I did a test on the latest beta and  auto removed:

gnome-software
packagekit

gnome-software-plugin-snap
gstreamer1.0-packagekit
packagekit-tools
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-software
gstreamer1.0-alsa
libllvm4.0
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager
libreoffice-pdfimport
ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola

So far it seems to work and lower memory consumption to 848Mb at boot. The only drawback I found is the [lack of auto codecs installation](https://medium.com/@iain.lane/codecs-and-packagekit-in-gnome-software-on-ubuntu-artful-447ddd70d3f9) , and the fact you have normally to add again ubuntu-desktop package before each Ubuntu reelease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No drawback that I know of.
1st thing I do after every ubuntu installation is to remove dozens of bloatware packages, including those.
As for codecs, just install vlc and mplayer (or mpv) which play everything.