# How to kill "Waiting to install" process?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm really new in Ubuntu or Linux as well.
I'm wanting to install Google Chrome, so I went to Chrome homepage and downloaded a .deb file. I opened it with Software Install and hit Install.
Then I saw a process called "Waiting to install" in Launcher bar. But it has been stuck for a couple of hours now.
I tried rebooting and installing it again 3 times but still got this problem.
I researched and knew this is a bug when installing by Software Install.
So I decided to install via terminal and Chrome was installed successfully. Now I can open Chrome and surf the net.
But the "Waiting to install" process is still there. I don't want to reboot to get rid of it. That is not a good way and I also don't believe there is no other software out there acts like that.
So what I want to do now is I want to kill it. But I opened the System Monitor and didn't have a clue which PID it is.
So please tell me how to kill it like an Ubuntu professor.

Comment: No need to kill any process. Reboot or shutdown whenever you need and in order to solve the issue just install the updates.

Comment: Why no need to kill any process? Is it can cause problem?

Comment: It's just not something I'd worry about. I would focus in solving the underlying problem instead which is trying to install other software without first fully updating the system.

Comment: I even don't know about updating the system. Thank you for pointing out me that :)

Comment: Search for and run the Updates tool. Couldn't be easier :) . Now, if you wanna go pro, open a Terminal and run the following commands: `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `xkill` in Terminal and the cursor should turn into a "**×**". Place it over the malfunctioning window and click.

Answer (score 0):

Another post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760034/waiting-to-install-for-ever-ubuntu-software-16-04) shares a related issue, if not the same, and the work around suggested is simply to install the .deb file straight from the terminal.  TBH, that's the way I almost always do it myself: go to the terminal, and type:

```
cd /path/to/file
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

...last line to fix any dependency issues that may arise; not necessary if you the dpkg command runs without any dependency issues.